# react-router : share state between Routes without Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I would like to have a shared state (list of clients fetched remotely) between 2 sibling Routes : `Timesheets` and `Clients`.
I want to try how far i can go with 'pure' React (No Flux architecture).

This example works, but I have an error : `browser.js:49 Warning: [react-router] You cannot change <Router routes>; it will be ignored` 
So, it doesn't seem to like async props.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      clients : []
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
   fetch("clients.json")
     .then(response => response.json()) 
     .then(clients => this.setState({ clients }));
}

render() {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Header} >
        <Route path="timesheet" component={() => (<Timesheets {...this.state} />) }/>
        <Route path="clients" component={() => (<Clients {...this.state} />) }/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Is it possible to send async props down to each route?
Or is it possible to set the whole state in the parent route (`Header` component) and then access this state from each child route (`Timesheets` and `Clients` components)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an [high-order component](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.kiyqyv6it) to fetch and inject data to your top level component. Then you can pass props to sub routes via `React.cloneElement`.

HOC

```
const FetchHOC = url => Component => class extends React.Component() {
   state = { data: null };
   componentDidMount() { 
      fetch(url).then(data => this.setState({ data })); 
   }
   render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} {...this.state.data} />;
   }
}
```

Route configuration

```
<Route path="/" component={FetchHOC('http://some-url')(App)}>
   <Route path="subroute1" component={SubRoute1} />
   <Route path="subroute2" component={SubRoute2} />
</Route>
```

Parent route `render()`

```
<div className="App">
   {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
      data: this.props.data,
      // ...
   })}
</div>
```

Comment: Both links are dead ;_;

Comment: What's the advantage of this over [FurkanO's suggestion to use Context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41109081/1028230)?

Comment: I think there are no advantages to use this technique over using Context API. But when I wrote the answer Context was an hidden API (not documented and not easy to use). The solution I wrote is still usable and quick to implement.

Comment: I know it was an old post, but the supposed fiddle link now leads to scam-sites and what not. You may want to edit/remove that link.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at reacts Context. Redux also makes use of Context. It allows you to pass some data down to all children. But you should write code to use this data, for instance you have determine contextTypes etc.

You can see details on [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) about how to use it.